# Django OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to run an opensource project in my computer. But I am getting this error. Please experienced a person share your thought. I don't understand how I can solve this issue. I am using python 3.6 and django 2.X version.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Fiverr/vulunteer/manage.py", line 37, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1346, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\Fiverr\\vulunteer\\templates\\admin:admin\\base.html'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Du you have `admin:admin` anywhere in your settings?

Comment: No. I don't have `admin:admin`  in settings.